# html validation error: form as child of ul

Tags: html

I want to put a form in my navbar and therefore wrote the following html code

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
            <li><a href="/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="top_navbar_center">
             <form action="/target" method='GET' style="display:inline;top-margin:5px;padding:5px;">
                  {{ form_search.hidden_tag() }}
                  {{ form_search.search() }}
                  <input type=hidden id="user_id" name="user_id">
              </form> 
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

however, my html validator tells me that this is invalid syntax

```
Error: Element form not allowed as child of element ul in this context.
```

so my question is how can I correctly include the form in the navbar?
thanks
carl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put the `<form>` inside of an `<li>` that's inside of the `<ul>`, instead of directly under the `<ul>`.

The `<li>` element is a valid child of the `<ul>` element, and the `<form>` element is a valid child of `<li>` because it counts as [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content).

You can find more info on `<ul>` and valid content [on MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul), and info about `<li>` and valid content [on MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li).

---

Your final `<ul>` would look like this:

```
<ul class="top_navbar_center">
      <li>
          <form action="/target" method='GET' style="display:inline;top-margin:5px;padding:5px;">
              {{ form_search.hidden_tag() }}
              {{ form_search.search() }}
              <input type=hidden id="user_id" name="user_id">
          </form> 
      </li>
</ul>
```

If you want to remove the bullet point, you can always use `list-style-type: none;` in CSS.